# Not able to catch exception with std::exception

Tags: c++, exception

i am learning exception handling in c++. I want the compiler to print what type of exception is causing the problem.But it gives an error instead and closes the program.

```
int divi(int x,int y)
{
    if(y==0)
    throw x;
    return x/y;
}

int main()
{   
    try{
        int a=5,b=0,c;
        c=divi(a,b);
        cout<<c;
    }
    catch(exception &exc)
    {    
        cerr<<exc.what()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[this is the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de5cQ.jpg)

Comment: you're throwing `int`, not `std::exception`

Comment: @user3365922 what should I throw exactly?

Comment: `runtime_error(to_string(x))` for example

Comment: @ShobhitGupta You can throw, and catch whatever you want (and whatever suits a particular problem). If you want to `throw` an `int`: just catch `int`. If you want to catch `std::exception const&`: throw `std::exception ("Some message")` (or instance of whatever class, which inherits from `std::exception`).

Comment: what should I throrw if I want the compilerprint the type of exception ? in this case division by zero error ?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `std::exception` has no ctor from string

Comment: @ShobhitGupta -- *what should I return if I want to the exception?* -- This is part of *your* design, not ours.  It's up to you.

Comment: @user3365922 Noted. Somehow I thought, that if `what` method is declared in it, one must be able to set the string, returned by it, while constructing the instance :/